# dotnet core msbuild doesn't result as same as dotnet msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

let's create a normal MSBuild file and name it `doSomething.msbuild`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="HelloWorld">
    <Message Text="Hello world" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

now if you open developer console or old school dotnet folder you can call something like this

```
C:\temp\msbuild doSomething.msbuild
```

I get an output like this:

[image]

now refering to [dotnet core doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild)

I should be able to do the same

```
dotnet msbuild doSomething.msbuild
```

but I'm getting this

[image]

as you can see I even tried to pass the target name, but no output is generated. if I ask to see all the preprocess I get this:

[image]

even both of the msbuild are using the same build engine version `16.5.0+d4cbfca49`
any idea how to fix it? or it's a bug?

Comment: Try to setup msbuild output verbosity or `Importance="High"` for message. `msbuild` and .NET Core cli might use the different verbosity by default. You may look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109090/why-am-i-getting-different-msbuild-behavior-between-visual-studio-2019-output-vs), the idea is the same

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @PavelAnikhouski

turned out with setting verbosity as normal I can get the same result level as msbuild

```
dotnet msbuild -verbosity:normal .\doSomething.msbuild
```

[image]